# Why is Appcellerator Titanium's terminal different from my OSs terminal?

Tags: node.js, titanium, aptana, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm having the following problem installing Titanium Studio. On my Mac (OSX Yosemite), the terminal shows that I have Node, NPM, Titanium, Alloy etc. all installed and 'callable' from any path. Titanium Studio keeps failing to run because it can't find the CLI.

If I go to Titanium's terminal view, absolutely nothing seems to be installed. Even 'ls', 'cd' etc. cannot be run. Anyone know what I'm missing here? It's like .bashrec never gets loaded or something. Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction,

cheers,

Wittner

Comment: Oops, sorry Loïc, thanks for the heads-up. They should maybe change that tag to mit-alloy? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Looks like this had nothing much to do with Titanium and everything to do with my system setup, but this might help others who experience the same symptoms.

Turns out that my .bash_profile was incorrectly set up.

.bash_profile is a batch file which holds information about (among other things) the current path. This file, if it exists, gets run every time terminal is started up. One of my path statements in the file ended without :$PATH

:$PATH concatenates the current path when you are putting a path command in the file e.g.:

```
export PATH=/etc/bin/
export PATH=/Applications:$PATH
```

The ':$PATH' at the end of the second statement ensures that the path now contains both /etc/bin/ and /Applications. Without :$PATH, the second line would have set the path to /Applications only, overwriting the /etc/bin/ entry.

So in effect all of the PATH commands before the last one had been overwritten. Terminal could not see where ls, cd or an of those command line tools were. My own terminal worked fine because I had it using ksh (Korn shell) which I had set up with some fancy colours and listing options. When Titanium tried to load a fresh copy of terminal, the PATH was effectively being overwritten and so Alloy, Node etc. where not visible to it.

I fixed up the erroneous PATH statements in the .bash_profile, restarted the app and now Titanium works fine.

Comment: I am glad that you found a solution. Please mark this answer as accepted to let other people know that you do not need help anymore.